# how to make view controller curved from top in swift

Tags: swift2

i want to make white view controller which contain menu items  curved from top as shown in image below[image]
i have implemented following code which making totally round edge view
not up from top

let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
         maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.curvedView.frame.height, self.curvedView.frame.width+2), byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.TopLeft.union(.TopRight), cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(10,10)).CGPath

```
    self.curvedView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

Comment: how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myRoundView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:myRoundView.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[UIRectCorner.TopRight, .TopLeft], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(70, 70))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = path.CGPath
    myRoundView.layer.mask = maskLayer

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Play with the number and UIView size to get it how you want it.
[image]
[image]